# Why O and N promote SN1 but C=O inhibit SN1 although both are electron-withdrawing?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, inductive-effect

[image]

**Source:
Jonathan Clayden, Nick Greeves, Stuart Warren, Organic Chemistry 2th Edition, 339.**

The general idea I got so far, is that, carbocation will be more stable if the + charge at central C is dispersed.

How can a very electronegative atom bonded to C bearing leaving group promote S<sub>N</sub>1? That electronegative atom should intensify the + charge, making the central C more electon-hungry, making the carbocation less stable, no?

C=O inhibits S<sub>N</sub>1 because it is electron-withdrawing, but why not O and N inhibit S<sub>N</sub>1 too? They too are electron-withdrawing.

Answer (score 1):

Those carbocations are termed as 'stable' as the O/N atom establishes a '2p-2p back bond' with the empty p orbital on the carbon atom carrying the positive charge. This helps the carbocation stabilize as the O/N atom shares its electron density to the starving cation. This effect is FAR more dominating than the pulling inductive effect of the O/N atom.

> C=O inhibits SN1 because it is electron-withdrawing, but why not O and N inhibit SN1 too? >They too are electron-withdrawing.

I am not quite sure what you are referring to, but I think you are talking about a carbonyl group on the alpha (just adjacent) carbon to the carbocation. That destabilizes the cation as the Oxygen atom cannot back-bond now with the cation. Now it pulls electrons owing to its negative inductive effect, or its electronegativity, you might say.